# Country dropdown is getting validated. But State and City are not

Tags: php

I am trying to validate country, state and city. But Country is getting validated whereas city and state are not.

Tried both Client side and Server side validation. Please someone suggest a solution.

```
<?php
$options = array();
$options[''] = BLANK_SELECT;
if (count($countries)) {
    foreach ($countries as $val) {
        $options[$val->id] = $val->country;
    }
}

echo form_dropdown('pcountryid', $options, $paddress->countryid, 'id="pcountryid" class="select2 req col-md-6 form-control" style="width:380px;" required');
?>

.......

<?php
$options = array();
$options['-1'] = BLANK_SELECT;

if (count($states)) {
    foreach ($states as $val) {
        $options[$val->id] = $val->state;
    }
}

echo form_dropdown('pstateid', $options, $paddress->stateid, 'id="pstateid" class="select2 req col-md-6 form-control" style="width:380px;" required');
?>

......

<?php
$options = array();
$options['-1'] = BLANK_SELECT;
if (count($cities)) {
    foreach ($cities as $val) {
        $options[$val->id] = $val->city;
    }
}
echo form_dropdown('pcityid', $options, $paddress->cityid, 'id="pcityid" class="select2 req col-md-6 form-control" style="width:380px;" required');
?>
```

//Server side Validation:
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pcountryid', 'Country', 'required|is_natural'); //Working Fine for Country.
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pcityid', 'City', 'required|is_natural');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pstateid', 'State', 'required|is_natural');

//Client Side Validation:
the value "-1" for the 1st option for $options array takes care of validating "required" on Country..

Comment: I think you forgot to add the code containing the validation of the three fields? How can we see what is wrong if the code is not there?